# How to close pipes in case of two sided communication (fork)?

Tags: c, linux, pipe, fork, popen

I am trying to create a program in C where the parent process reads a hostname from a file with the name **input.dat** and sends it to the child process. 
The child process will execute a shell script that will find all the users with that hostname. 
Finally the child sends the list of users back to the parent and the parent prints the list. 
I succeeded to write the code, and the program prints the list of users but doesn't stop. 
I don't understand at all how pipes work and I thought that I missed closing some pipes, but doing that didn't solve the issue.  
The code looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
int main()
{
        char command[50], host[20], buff[20];
        FILE *f;
        FILE *g;
        int pfd1[2],pfd2[2];
        char c;

        pipe(pfd1);
        pipe(pfd2);
        switch(fork()){
                case 0: //Child
                {

                 read(pfd1[0],&buff,sizeof(buff)); //child receives hostname from parent
                 sprintf(command,"./last.sh %s",buff); //getting the output from the shell script
                 if((g=popen(command,"r"))<0){
                        perror("popen failed");
                        exit(1);
                 }
                 while((c=fgetc(g))!=EOF) { write(pfd2[1],&c,sizeof(char)); } //sending the list of users
                 pclose(g);
                 close(pfd2[1]);
                 close(pfd2[0]);
                 close(pfd1[0]);
                 exit(0);
                }

                default: //Parent
                 {
                 close(pfd1[0]);
                 f = fopen("input.dat","r");
                 if(f == NULL) {printf("Error opening file!"); exit(1);}
                 fscanf(f,"%s",&host); //parent reads the host name from input.dat
                 fclose(f);
                 write(pfd1[1],host,sizeof(host)); //parent sends the hostname to child
                 close(pfd1[1]);
                 while(read(pfd2[0],&c,sizeof(char))) { printf("%c",c); } //parent receives the list
                 close(pfd2[0]);
                 wait(NULL);

                }

        }

}
```

What could be causing the problem?

Comment: You should *always* check for errors on all system calls that can fail (which is just about all of them). Especially `read` and `write`. It's even more important for `read` as that will return `0` if the other end was closed. This information should be in any decent book or online tutorial or class.

Comment: Furthermore, `popen` return a *pointer*, otherwise you could not assign the result to `g` (for example). It will return `NULL` on failure, not a value less than zero. I'm surprised the compiler doesn't warn you about this (and other things you do wrong). Enable verbose warnings, and treat them as errors. I suggest you add `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Werror` when building.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and suggestion. I was closing the pipes at the wrong time. Also I changed `g=popen(command,"r"))<0 ` to `==NULL`.